# How to make a Java program that will open the calculator app "X" number of times

Tags: java, runtime

I am trying to make a simple program that when I run it, it opens the Calculator app on my computer X number of times. This is what I tried to do, and it would only open it once.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            run.exec("calc");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a pause between each call to `exec()`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class appXtimes  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            run.exec("calc");

            i = i++;

            if (i == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Only posting code can be confusing.